# Django form error using ManyToMany relationship - TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Profile: user1>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am making a recommendation app where a user can recommend a movie/show/book to one or more users. The form is set up so that it displays a list of all users and you can check a box next to the users you want to send the recommendation to, but I am getting this error (`Field 'id' expected a number but got <Profile: user1>`) when I hit "Submit" on my form after checking the box next to the username and I'm not sure where I went wrong. Most of the other questions related to this are using `ForeignKey` rather than `ManyToManyField` in their model.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField( 
        'self',
        related_name='followed_by',
        symmetrical=False,
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="recs", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name="received_recs", symmetrical=False, blank=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.user} "
            f"({self.created_at:%y-%m-%d %H:%M}): "
            f"{self.title}"
        )
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Profile, Recommendation
from .forms import RecForm

def dashboard(request):
  all_recs = Recommendation.objects.all()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = RecForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
      rec = form.save(commit=False)
      rec.user = request.user
      rec.save()
      form.save_m2m()
      return redirect("watchthisshit:dashboard")
  form = RecForm()
  return render(request, "watchthisshit/dashboard.html", {
    "all_recs": all_recs,
    "form": form
  })
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models.base import Model
from .models import Profile, Recommendation

class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):
  title = forms.CharField(required=True)
  description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea(
    attrs={
      "placeholder": "You don't have to write a description, but it would be pretty cool if you did...",
      "class": "textarea is-success is-medium"
    }
  ), label="",)
  recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Profile.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
  )

  class Meta:
    model = Recommendation
    fields = ["title", "description", "recipients"]
    exclude = ("user", )
```

I thought the problem might be with how it is getting passed to `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, so I tried doing the following in my forms.py:

```
recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Profile.objects.all().values_list('id', 'user'),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
  )
```

However, that just returns a tuple of (1, 1) and I can't access the name. It also doesn't actually save anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because in your `Recommendation` you set `recipients` related to the `User` object. But, in your form you are using the `Profile` to populate your select, a minor mistake.

So, when you try to `.save_m2m` it breaks down, because the field expects an `User` not a `Profile`, a quick fix:

forms.py

```
class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = ...
    description = ...
    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    class Meta:
        ...
```

### A little improvement

So that an `User` cannot mark himself as recipient. We can [override the Form `__init__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) and by [providing an initial value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) we can exclude the `current user` from the QuerySet.

forms.py

```
class RecForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = ...
    description = ...
    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=None, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    class Meta:
        ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_user_id = self.initial.get('user', None)
        self.fields["recipients"].queryset = User.objects.exclude(pk=current_user_id)
```

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    all_recs = Recommendation.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
    form = RecForm(initial={"user": request.user.id})
    return render(
        request, "watchthisshit/dashboard.html", {"all_recs": all_recs, "form": form}
    )
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! This was driving me insane. If I wanted to separate out the form logic from the dashboard view function, can I do that? Or is it best practice to keep the logic for both displaying all the recommendations and dealing with the form in the same function?

Comment: Code related, the best practice is to keep them together as you can see in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#the-view) , within that aspect you are correct. But, think of a system. When it comes to a `dashboard` you want just to display information, about several system features (e.g. top5 users with most recommendations). So, in this case I would move this logic to a new view `create_recommendation` and have another `list_recommendation`. (In your example, `dashboard` IS the list view apart the rec. creation)